# ZFS Scrub Errors even after replacing RAM?

Tags: memory, zfs

I noticed my computer having a lot of ... weird issues. Crashes during compilations that were not reliable, etc. Finally, I noticed ZFS reporting data errors. I ran a memory test and got flakey, inconsistent results, but at least a few positive tests.

So I replaced the RAM.

But I'm still getting NEW ZFS data errors:

```
  pool: tank2
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices has experienced an error resulting in data
    corruption.  Applications may be affected.
action: Restore the file in question if possible.  Otherwise restore the
    entire pool from backup.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-8A
  scan: scrub repaired 282K in 0 days 00:03:06 with 259 errors on Wed Sep 16 20:11:02 2020
config:

    NAME                                                         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    tank2                                                        DEGRADED     0     0     0
      dm-uuid-CRYPT-LUKS2-0b09cd66bda2423d94aeece6e8217902-root  DEGRADED     0     0     0  too many errors

errors: Permanent errors have been detected in the following files:

        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/misc/unihan-database/default.nix
        /nix/store/3h8a27j9rs3bwi966pbvc0yvvv8m3dfr-clang-10.0.1/lib/libclangToolingRefactoring.a
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/development/compilers/graalvm/enterprise-edition.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/nixos/modules/services/games/factorio.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/quandl/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/desktops/lxqt/lxqt-session/default.nix
        /nix/store/6516v0d51z9ryn4i74xsir8ddaawnq6s-nixos-20.09.20200911.c6d9d7b/nixos/pkgs/applications/networking/browsers/chromium/common.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/hypothesis-auto/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/os-specific/linux/broadcom-sta/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/development/tools/jazzy/gemset.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/development/node-packages/node-packages.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/fonts/source-sans-pro/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/libraries/glibmm/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/snapcast/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/django-ranged-response/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/servers/x11/xquartz/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/supervise_api/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/os-specific/linux/broadcom-sta/linux-4.7.patch
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/interpreters/love/0.10.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/games/wyvern/cargo-lock.patch
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/build-support/vm/windows/controller/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/sl1-to-photon/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/nixos/maintainers/scripts/ec2/create-amis.sh
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/snitun/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/lib/strings-with-deps.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/nixos/doc/varlistentry-fixer.rb
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/slade/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/xcruiser/default.nix
        /nix/store/m1dc6px4gi38bn67lz2w65pdpj210knc-source/nixos/modules/programs/zsh/zsh.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/servers/mail/public-inbox/default.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/fonts/tai-languages/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/nixos/lib/eval-config.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/servers/sql/mariadb/default.nix
        /nix/store/3h6p41hyxli89cs94vxi5cmzmqrsgfys-unzip-6.0/share/man/man1/zipinfo.1.gz
        /nix/store/0gqjxs98lld7byb9fyc0nn8i0frqbpc7-steam-runtime/usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/gtk20.mo
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/face/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/tools/typesetting/tex/texlive/UPGRADING.md
        /nix/store/3rnmzqs1ig85bn0i83k96mjblhfk3a4h-source/term.c
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/tools/package-management/gx/deps.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/themes/adementary/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/nixos/lib/test-driver/test-driver.py
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/tools/package-management/gx/go/deps.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/schema/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/nixos/modules/programs/less.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/imagecorruptions/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/st/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/desktops/gnustep/make/fixup-paths.patch
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/xpdf/libxpdf.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/themes/arc-kde/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/tools/misc/system-config-printer/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/xpdf/xpdf-3.02-protection.patch
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/stupidterm/default.nix
        /nix/store/j3q3f6nmaif7lmqdsp8fg2hxxrd4w1gh-python3-3.7.6/include/python3.7m/accu.h
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/themes/cdetheme/default.nix
        /nix/store/25j8b9jslx78giaag5rqlv0snqqx8lr8-topgit-0.19.12/share/topgit/tg-tg.txt
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/desktops/mate/mate-desktop/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/regional/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/syncthing-tray/default.nix
        /nix/store/lzg82saim01xiv5hp3hrjzjf77lvrgs4-xen-4.8.5/share/xen/qemu/vgabios.bin
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/aria2p/default.nix
        /nix/store/6516v0d51z9ryn4i74xsir8ddaawnq6s-nixos-20.09.20200911.c6d9d7b/nixos/pkgs/applications/science/misc/openmodelica/src-libs-git.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/applications/audio/faust/faust1.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/applications/audio/faust/faust2.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/applications/editors/neovim/wrapper.nix
        /nix/store/j3q3f6nmaif7lmqdsp8fg2hxxrd4w1gh-python3-3.7.6/include/python3.7m/context.h
        /nix/store/b9yhh50866fxhv5r6ck164shhzrwzds4-gnutls-3.6.13.drv
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/fonts/kanji-stroke-order-font/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/synergy/macos_build_fix.patch
        /nix/store/3h8a27j9rs3bwi966pbvc0yvvv8m3dfr-clang-10.0.1/include/clang/Analysis/CallGraph.h
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/nixos/modules/programs/venus.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/tabula/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/python-unshare/default.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/themes/materia-theme/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/os-specific/linux/apparmor/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/servers/nosql/riak/2.2.0.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/speedtest-cli/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/Mako/default.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/themes/nordic/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/servers/computing/torque/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/python-vipaccess/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/nixos/modules/config/malloc.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/fonts/league-of-moveable-type/update.sh
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/themes/numix/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/nixos/modules/services/torrent/rtorrent.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/python-xmp-toolkit/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/os-specific/linux/displaylink/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/servers/openafs/1.6/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/seekpath/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/development/compilers/elm/packages/node-packages.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/nixos/modules/services/audio/jack.nix
        /nix/store/caalbaj31answcw6gjabf6xfsdaa8hk1-tzdata-2019c/share/zoneinfo/Antarctica/Palmer
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/zathura/ps/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/development/go-modules/generic/default.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/themes/plano/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/development/go-packages/generic/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/libraries/irrlicht/default.nix
        /nix/store/9n5lqbp762a3w58fq60w1r79gi1pv9h3-python3.8-tornado-6.0.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/autoreload.py
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/servers/dict/dictd-db.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/themes/shades-of-gray/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/nixos/modules/services/backup/postgresql-wal-receiver.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/terminal-parrot/default.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/themes/snowblind/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/tools/X11/xdg-utils/default.nix
        /nix/store/j3q3f6nmaif7lmqdsp8fg2hxxrd4w1gh-python3-3.7.6/include/python3.7m/odictobject.h
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/libraries/AntTweakBar/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/docutils/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/servers/tvheadend/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/development/r-modules/bioc-packages.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/maintainers/scripts/hydra-eval-failures.py
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/nixos/modules/services/misc/gitlab.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/servers/http/unit/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/restrictedpython/default.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/fonts/material-icons/default.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/themes/vertex/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/azure-mgmt-sqlvirtualmachine/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/libraries/jama/default.nix
        /nix/store/abwwg7bf8b5iv4pv7d6ap4g6haffdpyb-perl5.30.3-Starman-0.4015/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.3/Starman/Server.pm
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/tools/misc/pipelight/pipelight.patch
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/colorcet/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/maintainers/scripts/nix-generate-from-cpan.pl
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/tools/filesystems/ceph/default.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/fonts/merriweather/default.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/themes/zuki/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/servers/quagga/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/adal/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/dependency-injector/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/development/compilers/gcc/common/configure-flags.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/atom/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/nixos/modules/services/cluster/kubernetes/addons/dns.nix
        /nix/store/caalbaj31answcw6gjabf6xfsdaa8hk1-tzdata-2019c/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Hong_Kong
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/tint2/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/os-specific/linux/tcp-wrappers/default.nix
        /nix/store/fpbi6s249gzncvfam85jkq1n8i7mavqq-source/flake.lock
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/libraries/dbus-cplusplus/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/colormath/default.nix
        /nix/store/caalbaj31answcw6gjabf6xfsdaa8hk1-tzdata-2019c/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Irkutsk
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/setuptoolstrial/default.nix
        /nix/store/jy8s94j8fv3mrvs76c8gk2hb07nx5bhc-go-1.14.6/share/go/pkg/linux_amd64/cmd/compile/internal/ssa.a
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/networking/browsers/dillo/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/nixos/modules/services/web-servers/apache-httpd/vhost-options.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/nixos/modules/services/backup/automysqlbackup.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/desktops/cinnamon/cjs/default.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/doc/builders/fetchers.xml
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/pyudev/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/qmetro/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/tools/misc/fx_cast/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/qolibri/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/nixos/doc/manual/administration/declarative-containers.xml
        /nix/store/3q2g3bzffklr942sv2k0pwx4gn4q2z4g-ocaml-4.10.0/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs/ocamlmiddleend.a
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/development/tools/build-managers/cmake/setup-hook.sh
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/desktops/pantheon/apps/switchboard-plugs/keyboard/0001-Remove-Install-Unlisted-Engines-function.patch
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/tools/security/metasploit/Gemfile.lock
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/servers/exhibitor/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/servers/web-apps/cryptpad/node-packages-generated.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/interpreters/python/hooks/pytest-check-hook.sh
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/doc/languages-frameworks/bower.xml
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/networking/browsers/firefox/update.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/cachy/default.nix
        /nix/store/caalbaj31answcw6gjabf6xfsdaa8hk1-tzdata-2019c/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Omsk
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/networking/browsers/firefox-bin/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/networking/browsers/firefox-bin/devedition_sources.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/fonts/norwester/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/libraries/java/junit/default.nix
        /nix/store/qnicpaqwlcaph1yqbg7awjdm9j1sjv93-sg3_utils-1.45/bin/sg_ident
        /nix/store/0z2vcxri01blw8jas3kw2bzkskjp2dsi-boost-1.69.0/lib/libboost_wave.so.1.69.0
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/libraries/dleyna-server/default.nix
        /nix/store/8yiphz41v7sphvn8c4lwlxmgg6l7mncg-google-chrome-dev-87.0.4252.0/share/google/chrome-unstable/chrome
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/flask-limiter/default.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/desktops/deepin/dde-dock/dde-dock.plugins-dir.patch
        /nix/store/0z2vcxri01blw8jas3kw2bzkskjp2dsi-boost-1.69.0/lib/libboost_log_setup.so.1.69.0
        /nix/store/vrk2a0swa92d7wwnraxqlklx9xbnajkk-systemd-243.7-lib/lib/libsystemd.so.0.27.0
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/nixos/doc/manual/configuration/file-systems.xml
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/servers/monitoring/prometheus/json-exporter_deps.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/top-level/release-small.nix
        /nix/store/caalbaj31answcw6gjabf6xfsdaa8hk1-tzdata-2019c/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Srednekolymsk
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/canmatrix/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/nixos/modules/services/cluster/kubernetes/flannel.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/redshift-plasma-applet/default.nix
        /nix/store/caalbaj31answcw6gjabf6xfsdaa8hk1-tzdata-2019c/share/zoneinfo/America/Argentina/La_Rioja
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/robotsuite/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/nixos/modules/services/databases/openldap.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/libraries/gtk/patches/gtk2-theme-paths.patch
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/desktops/deepin/dde-network-utils/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/nixos/modules/services/databases/postgresql.xml
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/servers/web-apps/frab/Gemfile.lock
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/doc/doc-support/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/nixos/modules/installer/cd-dvd/system-tarball-pc-readme.txt
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/fonts/paratype-pt/sans.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/libraries/drumstick/default.nix
        /nix/store/caalbaj31answcw6gjabf6xfsdaa8hk1-tzdata-2019c/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Ust-Nera
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/misc/geolite-legacy/default.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/desktops/deepin/dde-polkit-agent/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/ropper/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/nixos/modules/installer/cd-dvd/system-tarball.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/tools/networking/maxscale/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/rofi/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/rofi/wrapper.nix
        /nix/store/caalbaj31answcw6gjabf6xfsdaa8hk1-tzdata-2019c/share/zoneinfo/America/Belize
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/nixos/modules/installer/netboot/netboot.nix
        /nix/store/caalbaj31answcw6gjabf6xfsdaa8hk1-tzdata-2019c/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Yerevan
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/doc/functions/library.xml
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/basemap/default.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/desktops/deepin/deepin-calculator/default.nix
        /nix/store/3h8a27j9rs3bwi966pbvc0yvvv8m3dfr-clang-10.0.1/lib/libclangCodeGen.a
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/build-support/setup-hooks/multiple-outputs.sh
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/tools/networking/dd-agent/datadog-agent.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/simpy/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/misc/drivers/epkowa/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/pyzmq/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/cbor/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/nixos/modules/services/networking/redsocks.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/nixos/modules/services/continuous-integration/hercules-ci-agent/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/azure-datalake-store/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/nixos/doc/manual/release-notes/rl-1412.xml
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/rpyc/default.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/misc/mobile-broadband-provider-info/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/nixos/modules/services/x11/display-managers/sddm.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/fonts/recursive/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/libraries/cddlib/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/development/compilers/go/1.4.nix
        /nix/store/caalbaj31answcw6gjabf6xfsdaa8hk1-tzdata-2019c/share/zoneinfo/America/Cuiaba
        /nix/store/fnssq7775pxa3i5ddna8754gm4qdsxwi-postgresql-11.8/lib/pgxs/src/Makefile.shlib
        /nix/store/m1dc6px4gi38bn67lz2w65pdpj210knc-source/lib/options.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/build-support/buildenv/builder.pl
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/nixos/tests/cockroachdb.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/development/tools/rust/svd2rust/cargo-lock.patch
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/development/compilers/vala/disable-graphviz-0.46.1.patch
        /nix/store/vrk2a0swa92d7wwnraxqlklx9xbnajkk-systemd-243.7-lib/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/systemd.mo
        /nix/store/43mlwkw0lwrmb7l6zbyzs0rf7kn1f94a-db-4.8.30/lib/libdb-4.8.so
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/doc/languages-frameworks/qt.xml
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/rxvt-unicode-plugins/urxvt-bidi/default.nix
        /nix/store/3h8a27j9rs3bwi966pbvc0yvvv8m3dfr-clang-10.0.1/lib/libclangTidyFuchsiaModule.a
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/servers/monitoring/sensu/Gemfile.lock
        /nix/store/3h8a27j9rs3bwi966pbvc0yvvv8m3dfr-clang-10.0.1/include/clang/AST/DeclObjC.h
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/libraries/glib/quark_init_on_demand.patch
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/rxvt-unicode-plugins/urxvt-perl/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/certifi/default.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/misc/shared-desktop-ontologies/default.nix
        tank2/nix:<0x8b28f2>
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/nixos/doc/manual/installation/installing-from-other-distro.xml
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/rxvt-unicode-plugins/urxvt-perls/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/interpreters/hy/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/amazon_kclpy/default.nix
        /nix/store/hrkc2sf2883l16d5yq3zg0y339kfw4xv-binutils-2.31.1/bin/objcopy
        /nix/store/3h8a27j9rs3bwi966pbvc0yvvv8m3dfr-clang-10.0.1/lib/libclangTidyModernizeModule.a
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/misc/sound-theme-freedesktop/default.nix
        /nix/store/a2kc2f71j9fw0l6r1zwm7n609lds21x9-source/pkgs/applications/misc/rxvt-unicode-plugins/urxvt-tabbedex/default.nix
        /nix/store/iza9ycb82dp9g7b27zprb7xmpnqpyp9y-cmake-3.16.3/share/cmake-3.16/Help/command/find_file.rst
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/hwi/default.nix
        /nix/store/ncq187s2lq9amm0mk3m2gdvx5sahyh42-source/pkgs/development/python-modules/rxv/default.nix
        /nix/store/3c6ayjnhl7c3lgqxlqa52bbpm8v7hn4q-source/pkgs/data/misc/unicode-emoji/default.nix
        /nix/store/9d9wnlml21v8b29sakraaw8vsav7ams6-source/pkgs/applications/virtualization/virtualbox/hardened.patch
```

Extra information: I've using a cheap PCIE<->NVME adapter for the Linux installation where I'm seeing ZFS data errors.

I'm kind of desperate for suggestions. I need to return the "old, bad" RAM still, but I also need to isolate which component is still causing me problems.

I've considered transitioning the Linux install back to a partition on my main NVME and seeing if the scrub errors go away.

But I'm really looking for some hints/tip/suggestions... Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think on-drive data isn't corrupted? What errors, *exactly*, are you seeing? Write? Read? In day-to-day operation? When scrubbing?

Comment: DanielB, because I'm entirely recreating the pool at various stages of testing. Anyway, here's zpool status: https://gist.github.com/colemickens/5aa7e4b4cef3f4ecfd0033192dd338e2

Comment: Seeing how all error counts are zero, the data currently on the drive is already corrupted. Your only option is to replace all corrupted files. Keep in mind that they may also be in ZFS snapshots (you have at least one deleted file with corruption).

Comment: The status is pretty clear: you already have errors _in your files_. Removing the culprit now won't fix them, it will only prevent next ones from developing.

Comment: Obviously? Did y'all read my post? I understand that fixing the files requires replacing them. The problem is, I HAVE ALREADY DONE THAT (and have repeatedly stated that I've done so), and corruption continues to occur pointing to an *ongoing* problem, even after switching out all RAM. That's what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have ECC RAM, you cannot eliminate the possibility that it is still bad RAM.

Check your MCE registers for signs of CPU errors.
Do you have EDAC module loaded? Are you seeing any PCIe errors?

Can you test the PCIe adapter and NVMe drive in a completely different machine?

Have you tried putting it in a different slot?

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. I don't have ECC RAM. I do agree that I could have gotten another bad set of RAM, but that seems like very bad luck.

For now, I have migrated the ZFS pool back to the motherboard-NVME slot and have not experienced any corruption.